# How to callback the given function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am fixing code but facing problems due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.
In the given function:

```
function submitQuery() {    
    disableButton();
    infoDisplay('DBQuery');
    enableButton()
}
```

`disableButton()` is for changing the image to be disable to let the user know that a  function has been started.

`infoDisplay()` is another function which carries some function at server.
while enable button is used to bring back the normal icons.

```
function disableButton() {
    idBRQuerySubmitBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Retransmit_Message_Search.gif';
    idQuerySubmitBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Database_Access_Search.gif';
    idQueryResetBtn.src='images/Button/Disabled/Reset.gif';
}

function enableButton() {
   alert('to check when it is fired');
   idBRQuerySubmitBtn.src='images/Button/Normal/Retransmit_Message_Search.gif';
   idQuerySubmitBtn.src='images/Button/Normal/Database_Access_Search.gif';
   idQueryResetBtn.src='images/Button/Normal/Reset.gif';
}
```

Here `enableButton()` is getting fired before `infoDisplay()` is completed. How to make sure **`infoDisplay()` gets executed before `enableButton` is fired?**

Comment: What is the code for infoDisplay? It is probably asynchronous no?

Comment: yes it is. and it's a very big piece of code and i can't post it here.

Comment: Give it a callback function parameter, so that you can use `infoDisplay('DBQuery', enableButton)`.

Comment: So maybe put the call to enable button in the success handler of your infoDisplay function?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to pass `enableButton` in `infoDisplay` as callback function. So modify your `infoDisplay` function as

```
function infoDisplay(parameter, callback) {
    //Do something
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Call function like

```
infoDisplay('DBQuery', enableButton);
```

Comment: InfoDisplay is called in other piece of code and if they do so without giving any callback function as parameter, would it be a problem? @satpal

Comment: @user2644549, Its already handled properly `if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function")` if you done want to pass callback it will will not break. just use like `infoDisplay('DBQuery')` still it will work

Comment: @user2644549, as you have not posted `infoDisplay` code and per your above comment, assuming your are making some ajax. write this in your success callback `if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a callback ability to infoDisplay so you can pass a function as a parameter that way infoDisplay can call the passed in function when it needs to.